Schazamio Python
I use this code example. I added it to the next loop. by listening to the audio stream every 2 seconds, 5-second segments of the recording.
After running the code it freezes after some time. I can't find any song, there is no error, it just stands still.
is there a search limit in this package?
import asyncio
from shazamio import Shazam


async def main():
  shazam = Shazam()
  # out = await shazam.recognize_song('dora.ogg') # slow and deprecated, don't use this!
  out = await shazam.recognize('dora.ogg')  # rust version, use this!
  print(out)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

I tried increasing the loop refresh time to 10, 20 seconds. But after a while it froze again
